# How to use SceneTransitionAnimation to tranform between 2 imageview have different rates

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I have 2 imageView have different size wait for transition.But the displacement process is shocked at the end due to differences in size

ImageView1 have size 340*340 ,ScaleType is CENTER_CROP
ImageView2 have full screen ,ScaleType is fitXY

This 's my code

start Activity1

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),Show_Picture.class);
intent.putExtra("hinhanh",caculator(position));
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
       ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat=ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(),view,"myimage");
       startActivity(intent,optionsCompat.toBundle());
}
```

get back at Activity2

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    /*finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0,R.anim.show_picture_out);*/
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height=layoutParams.width;
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated ^^

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `view` is indeed your `ImageView` and make sure that the `ImageView` in the second activity has the xml tag of

```
android:transitionName="myimage"
```

Comment: i did,but it always get a little slide

Comment: What do you mean by little slide?

Comment: each one of them take 2 different center crop,